# touch event on a quartz circle drawing?

Tags: iphone

I have drawn a circle on the iphone simulator using quartz 2d with fill. Is there a way by which I can detect a touch event on that circle?

Thanks 
Harikant Jammi

Answer (score 7):

If you have a CGPath of that circle, you can obtain a CGPoint of where the user's finger fell inside of touchesBegan and check to see whether it falls within this CGPath using the following code.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
  // Depending on your code, you may need to check a different view than self.view

  // You should probably check the docs for the arguments of this function--
  // It's been a while since I last used it
  if (CGPathContainsPoint(yourCircle, nil, location, nil)) {
    // Do something swanky
  } else {
    // Don't do teh swank
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but if the surrounding space around the circle is set to an alpha of 0, then maybe only the circle would accept touches.  You'd probably have to turn off isOpaque for the view, and have no background color.

If that doesn't work, then you'll have to process the tap location and write code to see if it is within the circle area or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a custom invisible button with 0.0 alpha on that circle, so the button will always be able to detect touch.